# Ordering problem / Probabilities and Statistics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, combinations

[Question Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y0nu.png)

> Four types of molecules are labeled A, B, C and D. If these four molecules form a chain how many distinct chains are there? For this question you may assume that is matters which molecule is at the "front" of the chain and which at the "back". Thus, ABCD and DCBA would be distinct chains
> (1 mark).

> What if it doesn't matter which molecule is at the front and which at the back of the chain? That is if ABCD and DCBA were indistinguishable? How many distinct chains are there? (1 mark)

I was able to solve the first question, it gave me $24$ chains which is ok.
But I don't understand why the second question shouldn't be $4$ as the order doesn't matter. In the professor's solution it says : $\frac{4!}{2}$

I was hoping someone can explain what's the logic behind the $2$ in the bottom...

I truly don't understand. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to give my image a name .. It's under the link "enter image description"

Comment: How did you come to the answer of $4$? What was your thought process?

Answer (score 2):

Try to think this way:

For each permutation of the 4 molecules, there must be one corresponding inverse permutation. (Because the first molecule and last molecule are never the same, neither are the 2nd one and 3rd one.) All 24 permutations in i) are in pairs without repetition and omission. In that case, the number will be halved after cancelling the inverse permutations. That will be $\frac{4!}2$.